# string search with two parameters

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml

I need to create a simple application where the Servlet reads two inputted parameters, check if either of them in the database the result should prompt "Failed" else "Success".
Please correct this code.Thank you very much.

PromotionServlet.java

```
package promotion;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


public class PromotionServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public PromotionServlet() {
        super();
    }

    private ServletConfig config;
    String page = "PromotionResult.jsp";

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                           IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        /*Establish connection to MySQL database*/

        String voucher_num = request.getParameter("voucher_num");
        String nic = request.getParameter("nic");


        String connectionURL =
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer_promotion";
        Connection connection = null;

        ResultSet rs;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        //List dataList=new ArrayList();
        String id = "error";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "mobitel#123");
            Statement s = connection.createStatement();
            rs =s.executeQuery("Select * from promotion_tbl where voucher_num='" + voucher_num + "' OR  nic='" + nic + "'");
            String voucherNumber = "";
            String nicNumber = "";
            if (rs.next()) {
                rs.getString("voucher_num");
                rs.getString("nic");
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
            } else {
                s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO promotion_tbl VALUES('" +
                                voucher_num + "','" + nic + "')");
                System.out.println("Data successfully entered to the database");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Exception is ;" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);

        if (dispatcher != null) {

            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PromotionServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>promotion.PromotionServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PromotionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/promotionservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

PromotionJSP.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%-- <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>--%>
<!--<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
    <title>PromotionJSP</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>-->

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
<html>


       <head>
       <title>Enter your Voucher Number and NIC number</title>
       </head>
      <body bgcolor="#999966">
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <form method="GET" action="PromotionServlet">

                     <p>
                            <font color="#800000" size="5">
                            <label for="Voucher_Number:">Enter Your Voucher Number </label></font>
                            <input type="text" name="voucher_num" size="20"></input>
                     </p>
                     <p>
                            <font color="#800000" size="5">
                            <label for="NIC_Number:">Enter your NIC Number :</label></font>
                            <input type="text" name="nic" size="20"></input>
                     </p>
                     <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>

                     </p>

              </form>
       </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code? What does happen when you run it?

Comment: Im not getting the output. as it should be either "Data successfully entered to the database" or "Fail". if the statement is true the result.jsp page opens which says "Data successfully entered to the database". This page doesn't open when i enter a new Voucher number and NIC number.

Comment: This is the result when i click on Submit button

Comment: Error 404--Not Found
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

Comment: You mapped the servlet to `/promotionservlet`, but the JSP'a form action points to PromotionServlet. Note the difference in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to print the result to the stdout stream instead of sending it to the result page. Use something like

`response.setAttribute("resultMessage","Data successfully entered to the database");`

and retrieve that response attribute on the result jsp and print it out, like

`c:out var="${resultMessage}"/>`

(or use the variable directly in the page)

Comment: How do i do this same thing with DWR.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DWR, but I think you need to make the resultMessage available in DWR so it can remote it.

Comment: Hi, its finally working. Thanks Vasquez. I sent the result to the result page as  request.setAttribute("resultMessage","Data successfully entered to the database"); and retrieved the response attribute on the result jsp as <%= ((String)request.getAttribute("resultMessage"))%> It's working fine.